# How to write regular expressions to match white space delimited multi-line column data

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text

So I have log files that come in the form of

```
n400_108tb_48gb           2   G    1,3-7                1       20G /  286T (< 1% ) 
n400_108tb_48gb:1         1   D    1-3:bay1-6           -      2.1G /   48T (< 1% ) 
n400_108tb_48gb:3         3   D    1-3:bay7-12          -      1.9G /   48T (< 1% ) 
n400_108tb_48gb:4         4   D    1-3:bay13-18         -       10G /   48T (< 1% ) 
n400_108tb_48gb:5         5   D    1-3:bay19-24         -      2.0G /   48T (< 1% ) 
n400_108tb_48gb:6         6   D    1-3:bay25-30         -      2.2G /   48T (< 1% ) 
n400_108tb_48gb:7         7   D    1-3:bay31-36         -      1.7G /   48T (< 1% )
```

That seems nice and simple to deal with so I can just write regular expressions to deal with that one line at a time.

```
([0-9a-z_:]*)\s*([1-9])\s*([DGPTE])\s*([0-9a-z_:,-]*)\s*([1-9])\s*([0-9.]+[KMGTPE]).*?([0-9]*[KMGTPE])
```

I mean, that's ugly but I can simplify it to

```
_name =  r"([0-9a-z_:]*)\s*"
_id = r"([1-9])
_type = r"([DGPTE])"
_members = r"([0-9a-z_:,-]*)"
_vhs = r"([1-9-])"
_used = r"([0-9.]*[KMGTPE])"
_size = r"([0-9.]*[KMGTPE])"
_disk_protections_regex_string = r"{0}\s*{1}\s*{2}\s*{3}\s*{4}\s*{5}.*?{6}".format(
    _name,
    _id,
    _type,
    _members,
    _vhs,
    _used,
    _size,)
```

Then I discovered that I have to parse files with this format.

```
s200_13tb_400gb  1     +3 system, vhs_de 1:0-23,      1      53T /  218T (25% )
-ssd_48gb-ram             ny_writes, vhs 2:0-23, 3:0-                          
                          _hide_spare,   1,3-19,21-25                          
                          ssd_metadata   , 4:0-23,                             
                                         5:0-23,                               
                                         6:0-23,                               
                                         7:0-23,                               
                                         8:0-23,                               
                                         9:0-23,                               
                                         10:0-23,                              
                                         11:0-23,                              
                                         12:0-23,                              
                                         13:0-23,                              
                                         14:0-23,                              
                                         15:0-23,                              
                                         16:0-23,                              
                                         17:0-23,                              
                                         18:2-25
```

and suddenly The expected values are

```
s200_13tb_400gb-ssd_48gb-ram 
system vhs_deny_writes, vhs_hide_spare, ssd_metadata
1:0-23, 2:0-23, 3:0-1,3-19,21-25, 4:0-23, 5:0-23, 6:0-23, 7:0-23, 8:0-23, 9:0-23, 10:0-23, 11:0-23, 12:0-23, 13:0-23, 14:0-23, 15:0-23, 16:0-23, 17:0-23, 18:0-23,
```

As well as the original formatting I presented. I don't even know where to start with white space delimited column separated values.

Comment: "Whitespace delimited" = tabs, spaces, or any combination?

Comment: It looks like it's just spaces but at this point I'm making no assumptions given the huge differences in formatting I've found in these files.

Comment: is your input unaligned like the second third and fourth rows of the third column or is it a typo?

Comment: Sadly, the data present is an exact copy and paste from the file.

Comment: Excel have this neat function[http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html ] which is able to make a table out of text files by slicing them in by a fixed width(the exemple shows only the delimited you should use the second), you could use that and a if statement to check if the previous lines is empty and them concatenate them. Them you regex it.

Cuz I don't think regex can work in this condition.

Comment: How large are the files? Would it be possible to load the whole file into the memory, then find the columns, and then parse every line?

Comment: Are there multiple records per file (for the *collimated* format)?  If so any indication of how they are delimited?

Comment: Can you determine the format from the filename or type?  Is there any header info that might give a clue to the data format?  Do the different formats fall into specific file date ranges?

Comment: The files range from 5kb to 2mb in size, @Banana.

Comment: The file names are just an indication of the processes that created the files. So Far I don't see any header information. The different formats are determined by what version of our code base generated the files. @wwii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a more dynamic method, which finds the column definitions itself.

**Explanation**

1. The script first looks in the file for columns where in each
   line the character is a whitespace.
2. It then defines the data column definitions based on being between whitespace columns. `+ [len(content[0])]` adds an additional whitespace column at the end making the last data column accessible if needed.
3. The data is extracted with the defined columns.
4. The data is printed if it matches the specific defined patterns. ***Warning:*** If you have multiple records per file, you will have to change this step.

**Code**

```
import re
from collections import Counter

# Patterns to save in the end, [name, attr, values]
patterns = [r"^([0-9a-z_-]{4,}$)", r"^([a-z_,\s]*$)", r"([0-9:,\s-]{4,})$"]

# Get file content, remove any trailing empty line.
with open('/path/to/my/file') as f:
    content = f.read().split('\n')
    if not content[-1]:
        content = content[:-1]

# 1) Find all single character columns in content with only whitespaces.
no_lines = len(content)
whitespaces = [i for l in content for i, char in enumerate(l) if char == ' ']
whi_columns = [k for k, v in Counter(whitespaces).iteritems() if v == no_lines]
#                                                .items() in python3
# 2) Get all real columns that are between whitespace columns.
columns_defs = []
for i, whi_col in enumerate(whi_columns + [len(content[0])]):
    if whi_col and not i: #special first column
        columns_defs.append(slice(whi_col))
    if whi_col > whi_columns[i - 1] + 1:
        columns_defs.append(slice(whi_columns[i - 1] + 1, whi_col))

# 3) Extract columns from file content.
data_columns = [[line[col].strip() for line in content] for col in columns_defs]

# 4) Save columns fitting patterns.
for data_col in data_columns:
    data = ''.join(data_col)
    if re.match(r'|'.join(patterns), data):
        print data
```

**Output**

```
s200_13tb_400gb-ssd_48gb-ram
system, vhs_deny_writes, vhs_hide_spare,ssd_metadata
1:0-23,2:0-23, 3:0-1,3-19,21-25, 4:0-23,5:0-23,6:0-23,7:0-23,8:0-23,9:0-23,10:0-23,11:0-23,12:0-23,13:0-23,14:0-23,15:0-23,16:0-23,17:0-23,18:2-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Define slices for the columns then aggregate the data in each line

```
col_1 = slice(17)
col_2 = slice(25,40)
col_3 = slice(41,54)
col_4 = slice(55,None)
one, two, three, four = list(), list(), list(), list()

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        one.append(line[col_1])
        two.append(line[col_2])
        three.append(line[col_3])
        four.append(line[col_4])

print ''.join(item.strip() for item in one)
print ''.join(item.strip() for item in two)
print ''.join(item.strip() for item in three)
print ''.join(item.strip() for item in four)

>>> 
s200_13tb_400gb-ssd_48gb-ram
system, vhs_deny_writes, vhs_hide_spare,ssd_metadata
1:0-23,2:0-23, 3:0-1,3-19,21-25, 4:0-23,5:0-23,6:0-23,7:0-23,8:0-23,9:0-23,10:0-23,11:0-23,12:0-23,13:0-23,14:0-23,15:0-23,16:0-23,17:0-23,18:2-25
53T /  218T (25% )
>>>
```

This will extract data from the *collimated* format shown in the example.  If there are multiple records in a file, the record delimiter needs to be determined.

Comment: This makes the massive assumption that every column is the same width. Read the comment: "I'm making no assumptions given the huge differences in formatting I've found in these files."

Comment: True that, but the info in the OP's post is limited with no actual question asked. This tries to solve the "I don't even know where to start with white space delimited column separated values." statement from the post.

Comment: This gets me closer to solving the problem, actually. It seems like (sadly) there are different column widths depending on what version of our codebase generated the files. But that changes the problem to determining the version and using different widths depending on the version found. Much easier problem.

Comment: Those ones and the plus-three on the first line sure look like they are delimiters - visually anyway.